# I'm confused on installation

Tags: wubi, system-installation, windows-8

I downloaded Ubuntu 64-bit for Windows 8.1, and on that little .exe file where it said restart to test and see Ubuntu, I restarted and nothing happened. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [Wubi currently does not work with the default windows 8.1 boot loader](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) assuming that you installed ubuntu in the "wubi" configuration. There is no easy fix for this at the moment (A windows bootloader limitation) that does not have you modifying your system bootloader.

Another option you have to try out ubuntu is in a [Live-CD environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD), which is included on the default ubuntu installation cd.

Live-CD is a boot option on the ubuntu default installation cd, that lets you run a full fledged ubuntu operating system using only the cd and RAM. When you quit out of the live cd any changes you made will not be saved (unless you modify your actual hardrive). This is great to try ubuntu as well as a recovery tool to use to fix broken or os-less computer systems.

However, in order for the live-cd to work, you're computer needs to be set up to boot from the CD instead of the harddrive (often times CD is checked by default but skipped when nothing is in the media), often times "fast boot" and some security options may disable booting from CD. If your computer skips checking the cd for boot media it will default to your existing harddrive and simply boot windows again.

If you restart your computer again, look for a message that says `Press F12 to select boot media` or something very similar, you may need to look in your computer manual to see what the exact way to select the Boot order.